# Can't install libjack-jackd2-dev on Ubuntu 19.10 Eoan with KXStudio repo as it depends on the version of the Eoan repo

Tags: jack

On my computer I have Jack and everything else installed from the KXStudio repo. I've been wanting to give audio development a try but when I try to install libjack-jackd2-dev, I get this output:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libjack-jackd2-dev : Depends: libjack-jackd2-0 (= 1.9.12~dfsg-2build1) but 2:1.9.12+git20190321~kxstudio1v5 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Here is the output of `apt-cache policy libjack-jackd2-0 libjack-jackd2-dev`

```
libjack-jackd2-0:
  Installed: 2:1.9.12+git20190321~kxstudio1v5
  Candidate: 2:1.9.12+git20190321~kxstudio1v5
  Version table:
 *** 2:1.9.12+git20190321~kxstudio1v5 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.9.12~dfsg-2build1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan/main amd64 Packages
libjack-jackd2-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.9.12~dfsg-2build1
  Version table:
     1.9.12~dfsg-2build1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan/main amd64 Packages
```

Here is the output of dpkg -l | grep kxstudio

```
ii  adlplug                                     5:1.0.1-1kxstudio5                        amd64        Synthesizer plugin for ADLMIDI and OPNMIDI
ii  amb-plugins                                 5:0.8.1-7kxstudio1                        amd64        ambisonics LADSPA plugins
ii  ardour                                      2:5.12.0-1kxstudio2v5                     amd64        digital audio workstation (graphical gtk2 interface)
ii  argotlunar                                  2:20180211-1kxstudio2                     amd64        Realtime granulator LV2/VST plugin
ii  autotalent                                  5:0.2-5kxstudio2                          amd64        pitch correction LADSPA plugin
ii  blepvco                                     5:0.1.0-3kxstudio2                        amd64        LADSPA, minBLEP-based, hard-sync-capable oscillator plugins
ii  blop                                        5:0.2.8-6kxstudio3                        amd64        Bandlimited wavetable-based oscillator plugins for LADSPA hosts
ii  boost-static                                5:1.66.0-1kxstudio2                       amd64        Boost C++ Libraries (static)
ii  cabbage-plugins                             2:20150918-1kxstudio1                     all          csound development toolkit plugins
ii  cabbage-plugins-extra                       2:20150918-1kxstudio1                     all          csound development toolkit plugins (Extra)
ii  cabbage-plugins-extra-lv2                   2:20150918-1kxstudio1                     amd64        csound development toolkit plugins (Extra, LV2)
ii  cabbage-plugins-extra-vst                   2:20150918-1kxstudio1                     amd64        csound development toolkit plugins (Extra, VST)
ii  cabbage-plugins-lv2                         2:20150918-1kxstudio1                     amd64        csound development toolkit plugins (LV2)
ii  cabbage-plugins-vst                         2:20150918-1kxstudio1                     amd64        csound development toolkit plugins (VST)
ii  calf-ladspa                                 5:0.90.3-1kxstudio3                       all          dummy package
ii  calf-plugins                                5:0.90.3-1kxstudio3                       amd64        Calf Studiogear - audio effects and sound generators
ii  caps                                        5:0.9.26-1kxstudio1                       amd64        C* Audio Plugin Suite
ii  cmt                                         5:1.17-1kxstudio1                         amd64        LADSPA plugin collection
ii  drmr                                        5:0.1-1kxstudio4                          amd64        sampler plugin compatible with hydrogen kits
ii  drumgizmo                                   5:0.9.18.1-1kxstudio1                     amd64        drum plugin comparable to commercial products
ii  fil-plugins                                 1:0.3.0-3kxstudio1                        amd64        parametric equalizer LADSPA plugin
ii  flac                                        5:1.3.2-1kxstudio5                        amd64        Free Lossless Audio Codec - command line tools
ii  g2reverb                                    5:0.7.1-2kxstudio1                        amd64        reverb LADSPA plugin
ii  helm                                        5:0.9.0-2kxstudio3                        amd64        polyphonic synthesizer with lots of modulation
ii  holap                                       0.0+cvs20100618-1kxstudio1.2              amd64        Holborn Audio Plugins
ii  hydrogen                                    2:0.9.7-2kxstudio1.1                      amd64        advanced drum machine/step sequencer
ii  hydrogen-data                               2:0.9.7-2kxstudio1.1                      all          advanced drum machine/step sequencer (data)
ii  hydrogen-doc                                2:0.9.7-2kxstudio1.1                      all          advanced drum machine/step sequencer (doc)
ii  hydrogen-drumkits                           2:2016.08.01-1kxstudio1                   all          drumkits for Hydrogen
ii  hydrogen-drumkits-effects                   2:2016.08.01-1kxstudio1                   all          effect drumkits for Hydrogen
ii  invada-studio-plugins-ladspa                5:0.3.1-1kxstudio1                        amd64        Invada Studio Plugins - LADSPA
ii  invada-studio-plugins-lv2                   5:1.2.0+repack0-1kxstudio1                amd64        Invada Studio Plugins - LV2
ii  ir.lv2                                      1:1.3.2-1kxstudio1                        amd64        LV2 IR reverb
ii  jackd2                                      2:1.9.12+git20190321~kxstudio1v5          amd64        JACK Audio Connection Kit (server and example clients)
ii  jackd2-firewire                             2:1.9.12+git20190321~kxstudio1v5          amd64        JACK Audio Connection Kit (FFADO and FreeBoB backends)
ii  kxstudio-lv2-extensions                     20200228                                  all          KXStudio LV2 extensions
ii  kxstudio-repos                              10.0.3                                    all          KXStudio repositories
rc  kxstudio-repos-gcc5                         9.5.1~kxstudio3                           all          KXStudio repositories (GCC5 Packages)
ii  leet-plugins                                1:0.2-1kxstudio2                          amd64        LEET LADSPA plugins
ii  libffado2                                   2:2.3.0+svn2652-1~kxstudio1v5             amd64        FFADO API
ii  libjack-jackd2-0:amd64                      2:1.9.12+git20190321~kxstudio1v5          amd64        JACK Audio Connection Kit (libraries)
ii  libjack-jackd2-0:i386                       2:1.9.12+git20190321~kxstudio1v5          i386         JACK Audio Connection Kit (libraries)
ii  lmms-vst-full:i386                          2:1.1.3-5kxstudio1                        i386         Linux Multimedia Studio - full VST support using Wine
ii  lsp-plugins-vst                             5:1.1.13-1kxstudio4                       all          Dummy package
ii  lvtk-examples                               1:1.2.0+git20150403-1kxstudio1v5          amd64        LV2 C++ wrappers and utilities - examples plugins
ii  lvtk-static                                 5:1.2.0+git20150403-2kxstudio1            amd64        LV2 C++ wrappers and utilities (static)
ii  lvtk-tools                                  5:1.2.0+git20150403-2kxstudio1            amd64        LV2 C++ wrappers and utilities - tools
ii  mcp-plugins                                 1:0.4.0-2kxstudio1                        amd64        LADSPA plugins designed for Alsa Modular Synth
ii  mda-lv2                                     1:1.2.2-1kxstudio2                        amd64        Paul Kellett's MDA plugins ported to LV2
ii  mod-mda-lv2                                 2:20160110-1kxstudio1                     amd64        Paul Kellett's MDA plugins ported to LV2 (MOD version)
ii  omins                                       1:0.2.0-7.1kxstudio1                      amd64        collection of LADSPA plugins aimed at modular synthesizers
ii  pdpulp                                      2:20180211-1kxstudio2                     amd64        puredata audio plugin
ii  protoplug                                   2:20180211-1kxstudio2                     amd64        audio plugins on-the-fly with LuaJIT
ii  qjackctl                                    2:0.4.5-1kxstudio1v5                      amd64        User interface for controlling the JACK sound server
ii  radium-compressor                           2:20180211-1kxstudio2                     amd64        radium's compressor plugin
ii  rev-plugins                                 1:0.7.1-1kxstudio2                        amd64        reverb LADSPA plugin
ii  rosegarden                                  2:17.12-1kxstudio1                        amd64        music editor and MIDI/audio sequencer
ii  rubberband-cli                              2:1.8.2+git20161227-1kxstudio1v5          amd64        audio time-stretching and pitch-shifting utility
ii  rubberband-ladspa                           5:1.8.2+git20161227-1kxstudio3            amd64        LADSPA plugin for audio pitch-shifting
ii  sherlock.lv2                                5:0.18.0-1kxstudio1                       amd64        investigative plugin bundle
ii  sineshaper                                  0.4.2-8kxstudio3v5                        amd64        Monophonic synth plugin with two oscillators and waveshapers
ii  sndfile-programs                            5:1.0.28-1kxstudio1                       amd64        Sample programs that use libsndfile
ii  sndfile-tools                               1:1.04~git20150311-1kxstudio2             amd64        Collection of programs for operating on sound files
ii  sooperlooper-lv2                            2:20150707-1kxstudio2                     amd64        looping sampler plugin
ii  sorcer                                      5:1.1.2-1kxstudio5                        amd64        Polyphonic wavetable synth
ii  swh-plugins                                 2:0.4.15+git20160216-1kxstudio1.1         amd64        Steve Harris's LADSPA plugins
ii  tap-plugins                                 1:0.7.2-1kxstudio1.1                      amd64        Tom's Audio Processing LADSPA plugins
ii  triceratops-lv2                             1:0.3.0-1kxstudio1v5                      amd64        polyphonic additive software synthesizer plugin
ii  vcf-plugins                                 1:0.0.5b-1kxstudio2                       amd64        VCF LADSPA plugins
ii  vco-plugins                                 1:0.3.0-2kxstudio1                        amd64        LADSPA plugin sporting anti-aliased oscillators
ii  vocoder-ladspa                              1:0.3-1kxstudio3                          amd64        LADSPA Vocoder Plugin
ii  wah-plugins                                 1:0.1.0-1kxstudio1                        amd64        auto-wah LADSPA plugin
ii  wasp-ladspa                                 1:0.1.4-1kxstudio2                        amd64        WASP LADSPA plugin
ii  wine-mono4.5.6                              4.5.6-0kxstudio1                          all          Microsoft Windows compatibility layer (.NET compatibility)
ii  x42-plugins                                 5:20200114-1kxstudio1                     amd64        Collection of LV2 plugins
ii  zynaddsubfx                                 5:3.0.5-1kxstudio5                        amd64        fully featured software synthesizer
ii  zynaddsubfx-data                            5:3.0.5-1kxstudio5                        all          fully featured software synthesizer (data)
```

The 
`sudo apt-get install libjack-jackd2-0=1.9.12~dfsg-2build1 libjack-jackd2-dev` gives

`The following packages will be REMOVED: carla-bridge-win32 carla-bridge-wine32:i386 dssi-vst dssi-vst-bridge:i386 jack-stdio jack-tools jackd jackd2 jackd2-firewire libasound2-plugins:i386 libjack-jackd2-0:i386 meterbridge qjackctl ubuntustudio-controls wineasio wineasio-i386:i386`

---

The output of `grep -r ^deb.*ppa /etc/apt/sources.list* --include="*.list"` is

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/freecad-maintainers-ubuntu-freecad-daily-eoan.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/freecad-maintainers/freecad-daily/ubuntu eoan main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/freecad-maintainers-ubuntu-freecad-stable-eoan.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/freecad-maintainers/freecad-stable/ubuntu eoan main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/kxstudio-debian-ppas.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/kxstudio-debian/libs/ubuntu bionic main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/kxstudio-debian-ppas.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/kxstudio-debian/music/ubuntu bionic main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/kxstudio-debian-ppas.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/kxstudio-debian/plugins/ubuntu bionic main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/kxstudio-debian-ppas.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/kxstudio-debian/apps/ubuntu bionic main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/kxstudio-debian-ppas.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/kxstudio-debian/kxstudio/ubuntu bionic main
```

I tried looking online if libjack-jackd2-dev is supposed to be part of the KXStudio repo but I have not been able find that information.
What would be the correct way of installing the development packages for Jack?

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy libjack-jackd2-0 libjack-jackd2-dev` to the question.

Comment: Please also add output of `dpkg -l | grep kxstudio`. Do you have added some of https://launchpad.net/~kxstudio-debian PPAs to the system before?

Comment: Sorry it took so long for me to respond! I added the output in the post!

Comment: Could you please try `sudo apt-get install libjack-jackd2-0=1.9.12~dfsg-2build1 libjack-jackd2-dev`?

Comment: If I try to install those packages it wants to remove a bunch of tools that I need:
```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  carla-bridge-win32 carla-bridge-wine32:i386 dssi-vst dssi-vst-bridge:i386 jack-stdio jack-tools jackd jackd2 jackd2-firewire libasound2-plugins:i386
  libjack-jackd2-0:i386 meterbridge qjackctl ubuntustudio-controls wineasio wineasio-i386:i386
```

Comment: It looks like dependency issue. How many PPAs do you have added to the system? Please add output of `grep -r ^deb.*ppa /etc/apt/sources.list* --include="*.list"` to the question.

Comment: Wow just saw I have Ubuntu's 18.04 ppa version of kxstudio! I'm was certain I had installed the ppa by following https://kx.studio/Repositories! Not sure what happened! Starting to think this may be related to a pebcak error!

Comment: Opened the  kxstudio-repos.deb as an archive and pulled out the file kxstudio-debian-ppas.list and inside it uses ubuntu bionic.

Comment: Having bionic on eoan may be a problem.

Comment: Yeah I'll contact the dev!